# How to extract entire chunks of text from a Profile Hidden Markov .hmm file

Tags: bioinformatics, hidden-markov-models

I am currently using a Hidden Markov model-based approach to detect viruses in metagenomics data. I use a profile made by the Pasteur institut based on vFAMs by Peter Skewes-Cox et al., 2014.

After using the profile with HMMer and providing translated contigs in every reading frame, the HMMs were able to identify the expected viruses in positive controls. Nonetheless, a lot of matches (with an evalue of 10^-10 or less for both conditional and independent) match to bacterial regions with 100% identity and ~98% coverage according to BLAST.

These false positives have something in common: according to the HMMs they match to endogenous retroviruses or giant viruses proteins (example: Zn-dependent alcohol dehydrogenase, ABC transporter, etc).

Therefore, I decided to see if I can eliminate these entries from the profile so I can diminish the false positives and made a list of all the families that have an annotation related to retroviruses or giant viruses.

I copy a chunk of my profile here as explanation:

```
HMMER3/f [3.1b2 | February 2015]
NAME  FAM007957
LENG  1078
ALPH  amino
RF    no
MM    no
CONS  yes
CS    no
MAP   yes
DATE  Fri Oct 12 20:02:22 2018
NSEQ  7
EFFN  0.591309
CKSUM 134316360
STATS LOCAL MSV      -12.5867  0.69540
STATS LOCAL VITERBI  -13.9281  0.69540
STATS LOCAL FORWARD   -6.9899  0.69540
HMM          A        C        D        E        F        G        H        I        K        L        M        N        P        Q        R        S        T        V        W        Y   
            m->m     m->i     m->d     i->m     i->i     d->m     d->d
  COMPO   2.52786  4.09835  2.76055  2.58333  3.30703  2.91930  3.80486  2.88354  2.60376  2.56225  3.71312  2.89938  3.51565  3.18472  2.93829  2.53713  2.89512  2.66587  4.91819  3.50321
          2.68618  4.42225  2.77519  2.73123  3.46354  2.40513  3.72494  3.29354  2.67741  2.69355  4.24690  2.90347  2.73739  3.18146  2.89801  2.37887  2.77519  2.98518  4.58477  3.61503
          0.16684  3.93795  2.00858  0.61958  0.77255  0.00000        *
//
HMMER3/f [3.1b2 | February 2015]
NAME  FAM006805
LENG  283
ALPH  amino
RF    no
MM    no
CONS  yes
CS    no
MAP   yes
DATE  Fri Oct 12 20:20:45 2018
NSEQ  8
EFFN  0.714844
CKSUM 174391985
STATS LOCAL MSV      -11.1126  0.70178
STATS LOCAL VITERBI  -11.7648  0.70178
STATS LOCAL FORWARD   -5.4313  0.70178
HMM          A        C        D        E        F        G        H        I        K        L        M        N        P        Q        R        S        T        V        W        Y   
            m->m     m->i     m->d     i->m     i->i     d->m     d->d
  COMPO   2.58563  4.40070  2.84295  2.49411  3.55282  3.12077  3.71148  2.77600  2.56241  2.36701  3.54429  2.93369  3.66844  3.05176  2.79705  2.67258  2.87961  2.67320  4.73491  3.80457
          2.68618  4.42225  2.77519  2.73123  3.46354  2.40513  3.72494  3.29354  2.67741  2.69355  4.24690  2.90347  2.73739  3.18146  2.89801  2.37887  2.77519  2.98518  4.58477  3.61503
          0.02701  4.02100  4.74335  0.61958  0.77255  0.00000        *
      1   3.09160  4.61822  4.21161  3.81854  3.28069  3.94629  4.51938  2.47147  3.57779  1.85500  1.11955  4.07700  4.40970  3.95105  3.76521  3.45517  3.40087  2.49434  5.14000  3.91374      1 m - - -
          2.68618  4.42225  2.77519  2.73123  3.46354  2.40513  3.72494  3.29354  2.67741  2.69355  4.24690  2.90347  2.73739  3.18146  2.89801  2.37887  2.77519  2.98518  4.58477  3.61503
          0.02701  4.02100  4.74335  0.61958  0.77255  0.48576  0.95510
//
```

My question is, how could I make a clean cut of the matrix comprised between HMMER3/f [3.1b2 | February 2015] and the // characters and matches to the names in my list (NAME FAM006805 as in the header).

I appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Francisco Iturralde-Martinez

Comment: If the file will always have the same length, you could extract the lines you are interested in using `sed` . For example, `sed -n '8,10p'` will extract the 8th to the 10th line.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the file is one option:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import re
IDs=['FAM006805']

with open('tp.hmm', 'rt') as inp:
  flag=0
  chunk=''
  with open('tp_mod.hmm', 'wt') as newfile:
    for line in inp:
      if re.match(r'^//', line) and flag==0:
        chunk+=line
        print(chunk, file=newfile)
        chunk=''
      elif re.match(r'^//', line) and flag==1:
        flag=0
        chunk=''

      chunk+=line
      if re.match(r'^NAME\s+', line):
        print(line)
        m = re.match(r'^NAME\s+(\w+)', line)
        tp_id=m.group(1).strip()
        print(tp_id)
        if tp_id in IDs:
          flag=1
```

Comment: You can update the `IDs` list to exclude them from being written to a new file.